# mod_rewrite and pagination with form get method

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im using mod_rewrite , pagination, and form with GET method. having some issues.

.htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles-author/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&page=([0-9]+)/?$ articles.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

which looks like: `http://www.example.com/articles-author/nelson&page=2` it works fine without any issue with pagination going to 1st page or any other page.

but when i try like `nelson?page=2` it shows the first page instead of showing 2nd or any other page.
can u please help me in this issue.

in the same page i have a custom page number field by using form so user can go to the desired page no by entering in the field, the form is given below.

```
<form action='' method='get' >
<input type='text' border='0' name='page' value='$page'> / $lastpage
<input type='submit' class='small color' value=' Go '>
</form>
```

when i enter and hit  `GO` if the `URL` is like this:  `http://www.example.com/articles-author/nelson&page=2` it will become like this:  `http://www.example.com/articles-author/nelson&page=2?page=1` after hitting `GO`

can u please tell me how do i fix these issues????

Comment: Anything after `?` in a URL is a query; you can access them in htaccess using the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

Comment: can u please assist me as per my `.htaccess` code???